# How to delete CSV specific row.(like user_name = Max)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, delete-row

I have a CSV file of around 40K rows. And I want to delete 10K rows with conditions(eg: user_name = Max). And my data is like :

```
user1_name,user2_name,distance
"Unews","CCSSuptConnelly",""
"Unews","GwapTeamFre",""
"Unews","WilsonRecDept","996.27"
"Unews","ChiOmega_ISU","1025.03"
"Unews","officialtshay",""
"Unews","hari",""
"Unews","lashaunlester7",""
"Unews","JakeSlaughter5","509.53"
```

Thank you!

Comment: `df[df['user_name'] != 'Max']`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Pandas library for this kind of problems and then use the .loc[] function. Link to the docs: [Loc Function in pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('name.csv')
df_filtered = df.loc[!(df['user_name'] == 'Max']),:]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided. See [answer].

Answer (score 0):

import pandas as pd

## Read the csv

df = pd.read_csv('filename')

## Create an index

index_names = df[ df['user2_name'] == 'Max' ].index

## Drop it

df.drop(index_names, inplace = True)